# PigLatin and print a message

Tags: printing, gruntjs, apache-pig, echo

I'm using a grunt shell of PIGLATIN and I am trying to print a simple message, like in shell ECHO "result is :" and then result given by Pig script . 
However I have done all the searches and no luck so far. 
Echo returns error , same as print.

I can't use UDFs...

Answer (score 0):

You can DUMP the alias or STORE the alias in to file to see the alias values.

**Refer :**

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch05.html#pl_dump
http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001811/ch05.html#pl_store

Comment: Okay i see that as a solution, but very inefficient...
Also, dumping the alliance will just print the result and not the text of " this is the result:" for example...